# NodeJS: Set path to FFMPEG binaries for module Fluent-FFMPEG

Tags: node.js, path, ffmpeg, binaries

I am building a application that uses the module node-fluent-ffmpeg. https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg

And I'm trying to package the ffmpeg binaries along with my application.
I want to do this so (especially on Windows) the user does not have to install FFMPEG manually.

Sadly everything I've tried results in errors. I've tried the following:

```
  ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath   : Gives an error saying setFfmpegPath is not a method
```

and:

```
  proc.setFfmpegPath    : Gives a createproces error.
```

It seems I'm doing something wrong. Could someone point out my mistake.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fix it! 
I did not know I had to include the binary itself in the path. So I made something like this:

```
  if(os.platform() === 'win32'){
     var ffmpegPath = './bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe'
 }else{
     var ffmpegPath = './bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg'
 }

 proc = new ffmpeg({ source: movieUrl, nolog: true, timeout: FFMPEG_TIMEOUT })
 proc.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)
 proc.addOptions(opts)
 proc.writeToStream(response, function(return_code, error){
```

Comment: One, can also use the shelljs module which will work cross-platform.
`var shell = require('shelljs');`
`var ffmpegPath = shell.which('ffmpeg');`

Answer (score 2):

In my case I have downloaded the npm i -S ffmpeg-binaries~ and after that I just set the process.env.FFMPEG_PATH to './node_modules/ffmpeg-binaries/bin/ffmpeg.exe'. This worked for me.